# Using Classes Static, slower than using it immediately?

Tags: c#, performance, class

I noticed that if I use a code from a static class, it´s slower than if I run it directly where I want it.

For example:

```
static class FastMethods
{
    public static byte[] GetBytes(int index, long value)
    {
        byte[] target = new byte[sizeof(Int32)];
        target[index++] = (byte)value;
        target[index++] = (byte)(value >> 8);
        target[index++] = (byte)(value >> 16);
        target[index] = (byte)(value >> 24);
        return target;
    }
}
```

There is the code I want to use in a separate class, so I can have it more organized.
Now this is slower than if I do this:

```
int index = 0;
long value = ms.Length;
byte[] target = new byte[sizeof(Int32)];
target[index++] = (byte)value;
target[index++] = (byte)(value >> 8);
target[index++] = (byte)(value >> 16);
target[index] = (byte)(value >> 24);
```

Both do the exact same thing, using the same numbers. If I use the static class, I will just write something like:

```
var target = FastMethods.GetBytes(0,ms.Length);
```

So, if I am not completely lost, it should be doing the same thing at least.

And now, when I say slower, I don´t mean a lot, I am talking about ticks.
From 1-3 ticks to 3-4.

It normally is at 1-2, and Static will be at around 3, not reaching 1 from my short tests at least.

Comment: Are you testing *optimized* code? If not, all data obtained are meaningless.

Comment: Optimized code? you mean the checkbox, if so, yes it´s checked. And by data, i guess you mean the results?

Comment: Yes, compiling as a Release build and either running without the debugger attached or ensuring that the "Disable JIT optimizations" checkbox in the debug options is *unchecked*.

Comment: I think we are talking about 2 different checkboxes. I meant the one in Build "Optimize Code" don´t see anything in debug.

Comment: You must run it as Debug->Start without Debugging (CTRL+F5)

Comment: So, wait, what is the difference between that and release mode?

Comment: Is exactly *that* the method you want to optimize?

Comment: @user2587718 Release Mode is faster than Debug mode, Start without Debugger is faster than Start. Release Mode + Start without Debugger is the fastest (or launch your program directly from Windows)

Comment: "Start without Debugger is faster than Start" ?

But, so basically, Release and Start Without Debugger is the same?
except it doesn´t build in release i guess?

Comment: And what do you mean with "Is exactly that the method you want to optimize?" 

I wanted to know if it´s slower with static methods compared to the code itself, which it was.

Comment: @user2587718 Sometimes persons don't read. **Release Mode + Start without Debugger is the fastest**

Comment: @user2587718 You gave a specific method. Do you want to try optimizing that method? It's possible that it can be made faster.

Comment: @user2587718 Debug/Release mode and Start with/start without are orthogonal. They act on different things.

Comment: Yes i saw that, but didn´t get what you meant when you only wrote "is faster than Start". But yeah, good to know, as i always use Release mode. And yeah if it can be optimized, i am all ear:)  // Oh didn´t know that, hmm, well thanks for the info, always thought Start with/without was the same thing as Debug/Release.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35666/discussion-between-user2587718-and-xanatos)

Answer (score 2):

Method calls always have a slight overhead when compared to inline code as there are context changes that are made when a method is called. More IL instructions are generated (pushing arguments, call instruction) than with inline code but the performance loss is very negligible.

Comment: I see. Does this matter in Release Mode as well? And does it matter with Static inside the same class as well?

Comment: Unless of course the code is inlined. That's controlled by the JIT compiler, done only when optimizations are enabled. It's also dependent on a variety of heuristics, the most important one here being whether the size of the code is <= 32 bytes of IL. I'm not sure if that's the case here or not, you can't tell just by looking at it. But the heuristics were chosen to balance the overhead of the call with the amount of work done by the callee.

Comment: When the debugger isn't attached it isn't possible to tell whether or not the code is inlined, but if the code is more readable when put in a method and is re-used then it's a better decision to put it in a method.

Comment: Heard this "Inlined" many times, but i don´t get what it means. 
And so no matter the method, separate class or not. it will slow thing down, and it´s faster to have all the code where it should be. But the cost is less organized code?

Comment: Inlined means when the code is generated within the same method. And it is possible that it may slow down by half a millisecond or so, but it isn't a given since the code may be inlined by the JIT or not when the debugger isn't attached

Comment: That is not a hard and fast rule, @user. Inlining means that the compiler will basically do what your test did: paste the code in the callee method right into the body of the caller, eliminating any overhead to a method call. But it only does this in certain cases, where it deems the risk of code bloat to outweigh the overhead of a function call. You've got to weigh those things too, when "manually" inlining code. I don't recommend it. Let the compiler do it's job; it's a lot better at it than we are.

Comment: Ah well that explains it.

But well, the problem is then, if you don´t know when it will inline, then you won´t know when to do it manually. As you can´t benchmark without the debugger anyway. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @user2587718: Of course you can benchmark without the debugger. You time how long it takes to execute something a number of times (using `Stopwatch`) and then report the time - that doesn't require the debugger. Benchmarking *within* the debugger is normally a bad idea, as it doesn't accurately reflect how the code will be run in real life.

Comment: Okay did a benchmark, and it´s superslow compared to inline. I get about 250ticks with manually writing it, and 1.4k if i use the static method;S

Answer (score 2):

> So, if i am not completely lost, it should be doing the same thing at least.

It is doing the same thing as far as fetching of values is concerned, but behind the scenes a lot more is going on. As calling the method has it's own overhead.

But it is never a lot and it is a very small compromise that you have to make for well organised code.